# Why does this command work in Lion but not in Mountain Lion

Tags: bash, join, osx-mountain-lion

```
alias crc32='cksum -o3 "$@"|ruby -e \'STDIN.each{|a|a=a.split;printf "%08X\t%s\n",a[0],a[2..-1].join(" ")}\'; }'
```

In Mountain Lion, it gives me:

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

In Lion (and previous I'm assuming), it works with no error.

I've tried various escapes within the join parentheses, but none seem to work.

TIA

Comment: The bash manual says: "Enclosing characters in single quotes (') preserves the literal value
of each character within the quotes.  A single quote may not occur
between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash."

Comment: Probably a different shell version and slightly different quoting semantics..

Comment: Note to self: try /usr/bin/crc32...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

The bash manual says: "Enclosing characters in single quotes (') preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash." – Keith Thompson